# Xcode missing constrains although app not using size classes?

Tags: ios, layout, size-classes

I have an older app which is not using size classes and I will not use constrains in this app. I did some changes on the layout (using xcode 7.2) and since than I am getting some errors "missing constraints" although I am NOT using size classes? And it is true from time to time the layout is wrong (but not ever?). How can I turn off constrains for this screen?

[image]

Comment: I suggest you look at `About Auto Layout and Layout Constraints` in the Help section of Xcode.

Comment: can you upload screenshot of constraints you have added

Comment: I would not like to have constraints in this app it would be too much work to add constraints to all screens! But I am wondering why xcode is missing constraints although I am not using size classes? And as I said before I will not use constraints in this app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let xcode set constraints then you can select reset to suggested constraints as follows..
[image]

Comment: I would not like to have constraints in this app it would be too much work to add constraints to all screens! But I am wondering why xcode is missing constraints although I am not using size classes? And as I said before I will not use constraints in this app.